# Chrome Remote Desktop not working with Pulseaudio

Tags: debian, pulseaudio

I have install Chrome Remote Desktop(CRD} on my vps.
As CRD supports audio transmission I wanted it.
but when I start pulseaudio these are the errors

```
pulseaudio
E: [pulseaudio] main.c: D-Bus name org.PulseAudio1 already taken.
pulseaudio --start
E: [pulseaudio] main.c: Daemon startup failed.
sudo pulseaudio --system #This works but it creates Dummy Output and CRD cant transmit audio
```

I have tried many solutions from the internet none seems to work.
Feel free to ask me any extra details

Answer (score 0):

The error message means that PulseAudio is already running for your user. Try killing it by running `systemctl --user stop pulseaudio` or even `killall pulseaudio` as your user. Then the `pulseaudio` command should work. This stop-and-start procedure can be in your `$HOME/.chrome-remote-desktop` file like:

```
systemctl --user stop pulseaudio
/usr/bin/pulseaudio --start
startxfce4
```

Ideally PulseAudio wouldn't start in the first place, but I couldn't figure out how to avoid it.